# Get all types with roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to use Roslyn to get all types used in a piece of code. I started with the following SyntaxWalker:

```
public class DependenciesCollector : SyntaxWalker
{
    public override void VisitIdentifierName(IdentifierNameSyntax node)
    {
        if (!(node.Parent is UsingDirectiveSyntax))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.PlainName);
        }
        base.VisitIdentifierName(node);
    }

    public override void VisitMemberAccessExpression(MemberAccessExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Expression + "." + node.Name);
        base.VisitMemberAccessExpression(node);
    }
}
```

But instead of showing me only the (part) types used, it also shows the using statements while I (as you can see) tried not to show the using statements. Can you tell me what is wrong with this code?

In short: I want only the types excluding namespaces. Is this even possible? (Things like System.Console are ok, System not)

Comment: I'm confused, you're first talking about `using`s and then about namespaces as if they were the same thing. They are not. If you write something like `System.Console.WriteLine()`, there is no `using` directive in that code. Maybe that's what confused you and why your code doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: In other words, could you show us a piece of code, the output you expect and the output you get? I think that would clarify things.

Comment: I do not want the using statements as they are just namespaces. System.Console is a fullname and not a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be a bit confused.  This code is not going to show you types at all.  It is going to show you the identifier names used in source, and any of the member access expressions (a.b).  Some of these may be type names, but most likely they are just code expressions.

If in a method body your write:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("x")
```

Syntactically, the compiler doesn't know that `System.Console` is a type name yet. It parses the pair as a member access expression, no different than the `Console.WriteLine` part.

In other syntactic locations, the compiler knows better. For example, in a local declaration:

```
Syntax.Console x = null;
```

The compiler knows that `Syntax.Console` refers to a type, so it is parsed as a qualified name, not a member access expression.

If you really want to know what types are used by the code, you should be using the semantic model to discover what type symbols these dotted names correspond to.

Comment: Yes, I already thought some of this myself, I didn't stop playing around with Roslyn yet :p but I want to make a program in which you can create classes and learn OOP. I want to be able to have interaction between those classes but you could also compile them one by one, unless one has an dependency on another. Therefor I need to know the dependency of a piece of code before I compile it. Hence I can't use a semantic model since it needs compiling (or am I wrong in this?).

Comment: But I already tried some stuff else but you're answer is clear and makes the most sence of all the answers I got (remi?) so ill accept it.

Comment: You don't need to be able to fully compile to use the semantic model, you just need to construct the compilation object. Actual, full compilation doesn't occur until you instruct the compilation to emit the IL bytes.  The semantic model is used by the IDE to tell you about types, give you completion lists, etc. It does its best to give you useful information even when the code is invalid or incomplete.

Comment: Nais, I am just new to Roslyn and started toying with it yesterday and so I keep learning stuff. Ill try to use the semantic model next. Thanks for the tip!